# How can I make sure only 4 instances of a function are running (using multiprocessing)?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I'm using python 3.6.6 and the `requests` and `bs4` packages to download and parse some content, now I'm downloading some bigger files `>1gb` and using just a single connection it is rather slow so I want to speed it up doing multiple downloads at the same time.

The important pieces of code:

```
def download(dir, link, name):
    r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
    with open(f'{path}/{filename}', 'wb') as f:
        for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=1024):
            if chunk:
                f.write(chunk)

files = [{'link':'http://...','filename':'somename.7z'}]
download_dir= '~/Downloads'

for file in files:
    #do some things to check if file['link'] is valid and that the file dosen't already exist
    download(download_dir, file['link'], file['filename'])
```

What I would like to do is to run what is in the loop in parralel, to be exact have what is in the loop running 4 times concurrently.

My first attempt to do something like that was using `multiprocessing.Pool.map` like this:

```
def download(dir, link, name):
    r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
    with open(f'{path}/{filename}', 'wb') as f:
        for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=1024):
            if chunk:
                f.write(chunk)

files = [{'link':'http://...','filename':'somename.7z'}]
download_dir= '~/Downloads'

datas = [{'file':f, 'dir':download_dir} for f in files]

worker(data)
    file = data['file']
    download_dir = data['dir']
    #do some things to check if file['link'] is valid and that the file dosen't already exist
    download(download_dir, file['link'], file['filename'])

pool = multiprocessing.Pool(4)
pool.map(worker, datas)
```

That unfortunatly didn't work and started more than 4 downloads at the same time, I assume it used 4 threads, but everytime a thread hit a network limit and none of the old ones were further it just started another instnce of worker.

In an attempt to force my programm to do what I want I tried this hacky way of things:

```
def download(dir, link, name):
    r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
    with open(f'{path}/{filename}', 'wb') as f:
        for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=1024):
            if chunk:
                f.write(chunk)

files = [{'link':'http://...','filename':'somename.7z'}]
download_dir= '~/Downloads'

worker(file, download_dir)
    #do some things to check if file['link'] is valid and that the file dosen't already exist
    download(download_dir, file['link'], file['filename'])

index = 0
while index < len(files):
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(4)

    for _ in range(4):
        if index < len(files): #check exists cause I'm incrementing index in the inner for loop
            pool.apply_async(worker, (files[index], download_dir,))
        index += 1

    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

But `pool.close()` didn't wait for all submitted tasks to be finished, instead it aborted downloads and apperently also didn't allow tasks that were submitted to the pool to be resumed once put aside.

What would be the right way to do this?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "a thread hit a network limit"?  Was an exception raised, or was the process simply blocked waiting on IO to complete?  Was there an error message?  How did you recognize this happened, and what was the network limit (number of connections, firewall, bandwidth, etc.)?

Comment: I'm sorry to be unclear on that, I assume it hit blocking IO because the code is running on a vm in google cloud with a download of at least 500Mbit/s but when I look into how much data is transfert singel threaded it is about 10Mbit/s. So what I assume is happening is that `for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=1024)` has to wait to get the 1024 bytes and in that time the threadpool starts another parralel execution up.

Answer (score -2):

Your code has a number of logical and style mistakes.  The biggest one is that you create a new pool for every element of your input list!  There should be only one pool.

`if (index < len(urllist))` is always true, because you are inside a `while index < len(urlist)`.

`pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=size)` is poor style; you should use `with` (aka a "context manager") wherever possible.  This will eliminate the need for `pool.close()` and `pool.join()` calls.  Like this:

```
with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=size) as pool:
    pool.apply_async(...)
```

Numeric for loops are considered poor style in Python when they can easily be avoided.  You won't need boilerplate like `index = index + 1` if you simply use `for url in urllist:` or similar.

Finally, you do not need to loop at all, because `pool.map()` (and `pool.map_async()`) exists and can do it all in a single function call.

Comment: Thanks for taking your time with the answer, but that dosen't adress my problem using `pool.map()` just results in python staring way too many downloads and not waiting for my `download` function to finish before starting with another one.

Comment: @usbpc102: Please post your updated code at the bottom of your question once you have addressed the bugs I have told you about here.  Once we see your new updated code we may be able to refine it a bit more, but I think once you've applied the suggestions in this answer your code will be pretty close to what you need.

Comment: I updated my post with a more detailed explnanation of why I did things the way I did them.